# DT::datatable - Select rows for deletion and write csv WITHOUT Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, datatables, dt

I've managed to create a markdown document, that doesn't call Shiny, to:

- load in a dataframe
- edit cells within a table
- write edited output to a csv.

Is it possible to  select rows for deletion, and remove these rows from the outputted csv, without using shiny?

````
---
title: "Test"
output: html_document
    
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}

library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

```

```{r edit_table, echo = FALSE}   

                            
DT::datatable(head(mtcars, 10),
              editable = 'row', 
              extensions = c('Buttons'),
              options = list(lengthChange = FALSE,
                            #pageLength = 8,
                            scroller = TRUE,
                            scrollY = 500, 
                            scrollX = T,
                            #searching = TRUE,
                            dom = 'Blfrtip',
                            buttons = 'csv'
                            )
              )
```
````

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: To have interactivity without shiny, you'll have to use Javascript and directly interact with the DataTables table.

Comment: You might be able to do this with [`library(crosstalk)`](https://rstudio.github.io/crosstalk/index.html). the DT package is "crosstalk compatible" and there are ways to filter data using for example `crosstalk::filter_checkbox()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way which uses the JavaScript library **CellEdit**.

Download the file [dataTables.cellEdit.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ejbeaty/CellEdit/master/js/dataTables.cellEdit.js).

Some custom CSS is needed. Save the following CSS code in a file **dataTables.cellEdit.css**, put it in the same folder that contains **dataTables.cellEdit.js**.

```css
.my-input-class {
  padding: 3px 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 60px;
}

.my-confirm-class {
  padding: 3px 6px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #337ab7;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.my-cancel-class {
  padding: 3px 6px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #a94442;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Now, here is the R code to put in your chunk `edit_table`:

```r
callback <- JS(
  "function onUpdate(updatedCell, updatedRow, oldValue) {}",
  "table.MakeCellsEditable({",
  "  onUpdate: onUpdate,",
  "  inputCss: 'my-input-class',",
  "  confirmationButton: {",
  "    confirmCss: 'my-confirm-class',",
  "    cancelCss: 'my-cancel-class'",
  "  }",
  "});",
  "$('#mytable tr').on('dblclick', function(){",
  "  table.row(this).remove().draw();",
  "});"
)
dtable <- datatable(
  head(mtcars, 10),
  elementId = "mytable",
  extensions = "Buttons",
  callback = callback,
  options = list(
    lengthChange = FALSE,
    scroller     = TRUE,
    scrollY      = 500, 
    scrollX      = TRUE,
    dom          = "Blfrtip",
    buttons      = "csv"
  )
)
path <- "." # path to folder containing dataTables.cellEdit.(js|css)
dep <- htmltools::htmlDependency(
  "CellEdit", "1.0.19", path, 
  script = "dataTables.cellEdit.js", 
  stylesheet = "dataTables.cellEdit.css", 
  all_files = FALSE)
dtable$dependencies <- c(dtable$dependencies, list(dep))
dtable
```

Here I put the two **dataTables.cellEdit** files in the folder of the R Markdown document (`path <- "."`).

You can edit a cell by clicking on it, and delete a row by double-clicking on it.

[image]

---

## EDIT: better row deletion

Deleting a row by double-click is not very nice. This conflicts with the cell editing. Here is another way, with which one can delete a row with a right-click. It uses the JavaScript library **jQuery-contextMenu**.

Go [here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-contextmenu). Download the files **jquery.contextMenu.min.js**, **jquery.contextMenu.min.css**, and **jquery.ui.position.js**. Put them in the `path` folder. Also download the four font files **context-menu-icons.eot**, **context-menu-icons.ttf**, **context-menu-icons.woff** and **context-menu-icons.woff2**, and put them in the subfolder `font` of the `path` folder. Now, here is the code:

```r
library(DT)
library(htmltools)
callback <- JS(
  "function onUpdate(updatedCell, updatedRow, oldValue) {}",
  "table.MakeCellsEditable({",
  "  onUpdate: onUpdate,",
  "  inputCss: 'my-input-class',",
  "  confirmationButton: {",
  "    confirmCss: 'my-confirm-class',",
  "    cancelCss: 'my-cancel-class'",
  "  }",
  "});",
  "$.contextMenu({",
  "  selector: '#mytable tr',", 
  "  trigger: 'right',",
  "  autoHide: true,",
  "  items: {",
  "    delete: {",
  "      name: 'Delete this row',", 
  "      icon: 'delete',", 
  "      callback: function(itemKey, opts, e){",
  "        table.row(this).remove().draw();",
  "      }",
  "    }",
  "  }",
  "});"
)
dtable <- datatable(
  head(mtcars, 10),
  elementId = "mytable",
  extensions = "Buttons",
  callback = callback,
  options = list(
    lengthChange = FALSE,
    scroller     = TRUE,
    scrollY      = 500, 
    scrollX      = TRUE,
    dom          = "Blfrtip",
    buttons      = "csv"
  )
)
path <- "." # path to folder containing the js and css files, and the font folder
dep1 <- htmlDependency(
  "CellEdit", "1.0.19", path, 
  script = "dataTables.cellEdit.js", 
  stylesheet = "dataTables.cellEdit.css", 
  all_files = FALSE)
dep2 <- htmlDependency(
  "jQuery-contextMenu", "2.9.2", path, 
  script = "jquery.contextMenu.min.js", 
  stylesheet = "jquery.contextMenu.min.css", 
  all_files = FALSE)
dep3 <- htmlDependency(
  "jQuery-ui-position", "1.12.1", path, 
  script = "jquery.ui.position.js", 
  all_files = FALSE)
tagList(dtable, dep1, dep2, dep3)
```

And now, you can delete the rows by right-clicking:

[image]